# app context lost when changing the location in Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have this piece of code in a Thymeleaf template, but I lose the application context when I am redirected

```
 $('#selectAuthorizedDriverId').change(
   function() {
      var link = "/deviceDriver/updateauthorizeddriver/" + $(this).val();
      $(location).attr('href',link);
});
```

This piece of code redirect the browser to the link, but without the application context, so I got a 404.
To avoid this problem I normally use

```
var link = /*[[@{/deviceDriver/updateauthorizeddriver/}]]*/ + "";
```

and it works, but since here I've tried

```
var link = /*[[@/deviceDriver/updateauthorizeddriver/}]]*/ + $(this).val() "";
```

but it has not worked

The URL I see is

http://127.0.0.1:1234/deviceDriver/updateauthorizeddriver/

and the URL valid should be

http://127.0.0.1:1234/driversApp/deviceDriver/updateauthorizeddriver/

Comment: And what exactly do your need here? To persist some data between sessions? To provide correct redirect within a single session? What's the code that produces error and what's the error? Where and why you think you need the "app context" in the code?

Comment: I need a GET request

Comment: What about buffering the context? `var that = this;`

Comment: what url do you see when you press the button?Does the $(this).val() has a valid value?

Comment: yes, it has  a valid value

Comment: what is the url that you see when you press the button?

Comment: ok, thanks for adding, and your cuurent url, before, the redirect what is it?In addition, I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This reason this is happening is because of the way Thymeleaf handles [javascript natural templating](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#javascript-natural-templates).

> Thymeleaf will ignore everything we have written after the comment and
>   before the semicolon, so the result
>   of executing this will look exactly like when we were not using the
>   wrapping comments

This is so browsers can view a thymeleaf template w/JavaScript without running it through a Thymeleaf parser (without having any JavaScript errors).  If you want to concatenate strings like your examples above, they should be moved to their own lines.  Like this:

```
// Original code
var link = /*[[@{/deviceDriver/updateauthorizeddriver/}]]*/ "";
link = link + $(this).val();

// Viewed as an unparsed html file (directly in a browser)
var link = "";
link = link + $(this).val();

// Viewed when run through a thymeleaf parser
var link = "/your-context/deviceDriver/updateauthorizeddriver/";
link = link + $(this).val();
```

Comment: the idea was no hardcode the context, anyway I will accept the answer if n one give me the solution without hardcoding the app. context

Comment: If you use the first example marked `//Original code`, it will work and you won't need to hard code app context.